# Looking for NSMutableDate class

Tags: ios, nsdate, mutable

Is there such third-party extension of `NSDate`?

I need some methods to adjust date (increase or decrease day/month/year) and keep the date object in the same memory (so `myDate = getNewDateByAdjustingOldOne (myDate);` would not be acceptable).

If there is no already implemented mutable date, can it be possible to get internal `NSDate` data (considering that there is no access to internal data in `NSDate` class interface).

Answer (score 1):

You could have all your objects that need the shared `NSDate` object store a pointer to the pointer, i.e.

```
NSDate** pDate
```

Then have all their operations perform on `&pDate`. In the class where you are adjusting the date, just keep resetting

```
&pDate = NSDate* *newDate*
```

All the objects will be in sync then.

Comment: Understood... This looks like a wrapper above `NSDate`. Not so elegant as `NSDate` subclass but should work.

Comment: Depends on how you look at it. A subclass is a whole separate class. In this case, you don't have any extra classes, which I would prefer to a separate wrapper class. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Really the memory overhead of doing myDate = getNewDateByAdjustingOldOne (myDate); is so small I really wouldn't worry about it.  Premature optimisation can result in totally avoidable bugs.

Comment: The reason is that other objects keep reference to `myData` and I should sync them manually after adjusting.

Comment: If you need to maintain all references intact, you can always create a wrapping object and use a pointer to that instead.  Would be a good way to avoid having to update all references to your date.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents` for a mutable dates. Either set up "pre-made" `NSDateComponents` to add/subtract defaults amounts of time or make them as needed.

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [NSDateComponents alloc] init];
comps.day = 1;
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
// will wind up adding 1 day to the original date.
NSDate *newDate = [cal dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:origDate options:NSWrapCalendarComponents];
```

Apple wrote some nice doc on [Calendrical Calculations](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007836-SW3).